# JavaScript + Chrome - Event capture

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to figure out how events are working. I have this piece of code:

```
document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);    
document.onmousemove = mousePos;    
document.onkeypress = keyPressed;

var keyStroke = 0;
var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;

function mousePos(e) { 
    console.log(e); 
    mouseX = e.pageX;
    mouseY = e.pageY; 
    document.formex.mousex.value = mouseX; 
    document.formex.mousey.value = mouseY; 
    return true; 
}       

function keyPressed(e) { 
    console.log(e);
    keyClicked = e.key; 
    document.formex.keypress.value = keyStroke; 
    return true; 
}
```

What confuses me - inside of keyPressed function `console.log(e)` yields KeyboardEvent, inside of `mousePos(e)` it yields MouseEvent. I can't tell how the differentiation between these two ***'e'*** happens?

Comment: `captureEvents` is both non-standard and deprecated. What's your goal in using it?

Comment: Hi, at this point my goal is purely academical - better understanding of how these two parameters are differentiated by the browser, even though on the surface they seem identical. Thanks.

Comment: I understand the overall goal of the question. What, specifically, is the goal of using a non-standard, deprecated function as part of that?

Comment: None, I saw it in an old but eloquent video tutorial. Thanks for the emphasis on its deprecation. Would you suggest any quality material on JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What confuses me - inside of `keyPressed` function `console.log(e)` yields `KeyboardEvent`, inside of `mousePos(e)` it yields `MouseEvent`. I can't tell how the differentiation between these two 'e' happens?

The browser creates event objects and fires them at the document elements. When the event relates to the keyboard, the browser creates a `KeyboardEvent`. When it relates to the mouse, it fires a `MouseEvent`. If it relates to something else, it will create and fire a different kind of event.

The "differentiation" is based on what caused the event to be fired: A keyboard action or a mouse action.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, but I had a feeling that I'm missing something fundamental.  The part that confused me:  `document.onmousemove = mousePos;     
document.onkeypress = keyPressed; `. Do we read it from left to right (document on mousemove call `mousePos` and pass your 'e')?

Comment: @YevgenyKozlov: Effectively, yes. Note that attaching event handlers in that way is not really preferred, best to use `addEventListener` instead.